# Domain credentials not working on Windows 8.1 after reboot

Tags: domain, active-directory, windows-8.1, credentials

On my new Windows 8.1 laptop installation, I can log in with my domain credentials when on the office/domain network. After hibernating the laptop and taking it offline I can still use my domain credentials to unlock the existing desktop session, indicating that Windows has successfully cached my credentials.

While still offline, if I reboot the machine however, I get a "The password is incorrect" error when authenticating with my domain account.

How do I make sure the cached credentials persists after a reboot?

Comment: Was this installation upgraded from Windows 8 or was it a fresh installation.  If you didn't remove the computer from the domain before you upgraded that could cause a problem.

Comment: Fresh install, no upgrade

Comment: It seems like you solved this. The next question I was going to ask you if the name of the computer was unique.

Comment: You think it fails Kerberos auth on the office because of dup SPNs, and fall back to NTLM?

Comment: My line of thought was that if the computer name wasn't unique or was the name of a previous Windows 8 machine that it would be trying to use credentials or other attributes that wasn't valid for Windows 8.1 because of a change.  It was simply going to be something I was going to suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by removing my Windows Indentity credentials from the Credential Manager in the Control Panel, and adding it again.

The "Persistence" attribute for the credentials then changed from "Logon Session" to "Enterprise", and I'm now able to reboot/logoff and log in again while away from the network